# $C^\infty$-curvature of Kawamata's singular hermitian metric

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, minimal-model-program

Let $X,Y$ are two projective varieties and $f:X\to Y$ is an Iitaka fibration. Consider the following singular hermitian metric $$h(\sigma,\sigma)=\left(\int_{X_y}|\sigma|^{\frac{2}{m!}}\right)^{m!}$$ where $y\in Y$ and $\sigma$ is a section of $$\frac{1}{m!}f_*\mathcal O_X(m!K_{X/Y})|_{X_y}$$

> then, the curvature of hermitian metric $h$, i.e., $\sqrt{-1}\Theta_h$
>   is $C^\infty$? A counter-example for it is appreciated.
>
> Under which assumption on $X,Y$ it can be $C^\infty$?

.

> Is there any singular hermitian metric on $$\frac{1}{m!}f_*\mathcal
>  O_X(m!K_{X/Y})$$ such that its curvature is $C^\infty$

Comment: If the curvature of a singular Hermitian metric on a holomorphic line bundle is $C^\infty$ then so is the metric itself. Indeed, we can write $h=h_0e^{-\varphi}$ where $h_0$ is a smooth Hermitian metric and $\varphi$ is quasi-psh. Your assumption is that $\Theta_{h_0}+dd^c\varphi$ is smooth. In particular, the Laplacian of $\varphi$ is smooth, so by local elliptic estimates you obtain than $\varphi$ is smooth.

Comment: Thank you. But you repeated my question again, since by definition $\Theta_h=Θ_{h_0}+dd^cφ $, ;)

Comment: What do you mean repeated your question? I answered it. There is no genuinely singular metric on a line bundle whose curvature is smooth!

Comment: If $X_0$ only has canonical singularities, or if $X$
is smooth and $X_0$ only has isolated ordinary quadratic singularities, then such $L^2$ metric is continuous. See Remark 2.10. of https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/christophe.mourougane/recherche/metric/CDG-terminal%202A.pdf

Comment: continuous is not the same as smooth! Your question here is about smooth curvature